# Debezium content based router setup unable to find DebeziumException

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to setup a Debezium source connector *in docker* which uses `ContentBasedRouting` and I'm following the [official doc](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/content-based-routing.html).

I have all the following dependencies in `/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql`:

```
antlr4-runtime-4.7.2.jar                  groovy-3.0.9.jar
debezium-connector-mysql-1.0.3.Final.jar  groovy-json-3.0.9.jar
debezium-core-1.0.3.Final.jar             groovy-jsr223-3.0.9.jar
debezium-ddl-parser-1.0.3.Final.jar       mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.19.1.jar
debezium-scripting-1.7.2.Final.jar        mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar
```

At the moment I'm trying to add the connector with the following transforms:

```
 "transforms": "route",
 "transforms.route.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter",
 "transforms.route.language": "jsr223.groovy",
 "transforms.route.topic.expression": "value.after.name == 'x' ? 'topic1' : null",
 "transforms.route.null.handling.mode": "drop"
```

I get http status 500 and the log:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:852)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:544)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1581)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1307)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:482)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1549)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1204)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:494)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:374)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:268)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
   ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
   at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:719)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig.enrich(ConnectorConfig.java:308)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:302)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$6.call(DistributedHerder.java:745)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$6.call(DistributedHerder.java:742)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:342)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:282)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
   ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.DebeziumException
   at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
   ... 14 more
```

Tried adding a connector without the transform (everything else unchanged) and it worked.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would assume the listed exception class is part of `debezium-core`, so seems like the classpath might be misconfigured. You should check the contents of that (and other) JARs to see if the listed missing class does exist

Comment: I used jar -tf on all the debezium jars and didn't find this class, also tried on a newer debezium-core-1.7.2 and it wasn't there. In the first place, I got all those files from the debezium examples repo - https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/main/unwrap-smt (in fact, i'm playing with literally the same docker from the example...)

Comment: I'm not really sure. You should be able to report issues here - https://issues.redhat.com/projects/DBZ/issues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved it by starting from clean environment because I've probably played with a mix of too many versions. Made sure I'm using Debezium 1.8 for everything and maybe the weirdest thing is that I had to put all the Debezium jars on the `connect` container in `/kafka/libs` because it didn't work in `/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql` for some reason...

Comment: This work for me. That transform need to put in the plugin dir