# Error creating a Connector in Debezium using a Transform

Tags: debezium, connector

I am running Debezium on a new EC2 instance, Ubuntu 22.04, connected to MSK, AWS hosted Kafka.

I'm trying to set up a Debezium source connector. I followed the Message Filtering guide here https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html (The connector works well if I omit the transform related fields)

I have Debezium scripting, groovy and groovy-jsr223 jars in /usr/share/java and restarted Debezium.

The lines of the connector with the transform fields are:

```
"transforms": "filter",
"transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
"transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
"transforms.filter.condition":"value.op == 'u' && value.before.id == 1"
```

When I try to create a connector using Curl, I get the following response

```
{
"servlet":"org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-54329480",
"message":"Request failed.",
"url":"/connectors",
"status":"500"
}
```

The following is visible in the logs

```
Jun  7 21:05:02 ip-172-30-0-105 connect-distributed.sh[23978]: [2023-06-07 21:05:02,528] WARN /connectors (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel:776)
Jun  7 21:05:02 ip-172-30-0-105 connect-distributed.sh[23978]: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/config/EnumeratedValue
```

This is very similar to another SO post though I have started over twice without success [Debezium content based router setup unable to find DebeziumException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70432710/debezium-content-based-router-setup-unable-to-find-debeziumexception)

Would anyone be able to help?